# Python Inheritance 2.7 Constructor Not Working

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, constructor

IDE PyCharm
Python Version 2.7

I have been trying to figure out how to get inheritance in constructors to work for a while now, but I'm still having issues.

I have a super class Person:

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name, address, email, phoneNumber):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.email = email
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
```

And a sub class Worker, that is in a different python file within the project:

```
from Person import Person
class Worker(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, address, email, phoneNumber, title):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(name, address, email, phoneNumber)
        self.title = title

However, when I try to make a Worker like this:
w = Worker("Paul", "Adrees", "@", "#" "worker")
```

I get the error:
w = Worker("Paul", "Adrees", "@", "#" "worker")
TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 6 arguments (5 given)

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the "," between "#" and "worker", that why it makes 5 arguments when 6 are expected according to `Worker.__init__` signature. Try this:

```
w = Worker("Paul", "Adrees", "@", "#", "worker")
```

It works for me !